# Will Box::new() make a copy from stack to heap?

Tags: rust

From the doc it says:

> ```
> pub fn new(x: T) -> Box<T>
> ```
>
> Allocates memory on the heap and then places `x` into it.

But "place" is a tricky word. If we write

```
let arr_boxed = Box::new([0;1000]);
```

Will the `[0;1000]` be initialized on the heap in-place?

If we write

```
let arr = [0;1000];
let arr_boxed = Box::new(arr);
```

Will the compiler be smart enough to initialize the `[0;1000]` on the heap in the first place?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Will Box::new() make a copy from stack to heap?

Sometimes. The Rust language does not guarantee this optimization to happen, and seems to leave it up to LLVM to figure this out.
Because of this, it doesn't matter at all if you initialize the array
first and then pass it, as that is essentially the same thing for the backend.

In practice, performance will depend on the case.
The example you gave is actually special, because the data is all zeroes:

```rust
pub fn foo() -> Box<[i32; 1000]> {
    return Box::new([0; 1000]);
}
```

In my [testing](https://godbolt.org/z/adfTnGdYM), the compiler was able to turn that into an allocation + a call to `memset` on the heap data.

*Note*: only with optimizations turned on though. In debug mode it will copy.

---

On the other hand, you might want to initialize your data with a known value:

```rust
pub fn bar(v: i32) -> Box<[i32; 1000]> {
    return Box::new([v; 1000]);
}
```

[Much to my horror](https://godbolt.org/z/cEdq5x9vq), the compiler decides
to initialize the entire data on the stack, and then call `memcpy`. (At least it unrolled the fill loop) :).
This happens even for really large data like `[v; 100000]`, which will crash your program with a stack overflow. Using a compile time known (non zero) literal like `[64; 100000]` behaves the same way.

---

If you *really* want to make sure, you could do something like this:

```
pub fn baz(v: i32) -> Box<[i32; 1000]>{
    unsafe {
        let b = std::alloc::alloc(
            std::alloc::Layout::array::<i32>(1000).unwrap_unchecked()
        ) as *mut i32;
        for i in 0..1000 {
            *b.add(i) = v;
        }
        Box::from_raw(b as *mut [i32; 1000])
    }
}
```

which does [the right thing](https://godbolt.org/z/ehb6fqvef).

---

A safe version of `baz` would be:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

pub fn quux(v: i32) -> Box<[i32; 1000]> {
    let mut b = Vec::with_capacity(1000);
    b.extend(std::iter::repeat(v).take(1000));
    b.into_boxed_slice().try_into().unwrap()
}
```

Which the compiler optimizes [quite nicely](https://godbolt.org/z/Pa4x6Y1vY), to essentially the identical assembly as `baz`.

---

Even shorter would be

`vec![v; 1000].into_boxed_slice().try_into::<Box<[i32; 1000]>>().unwrap()`

which is probably the best version.

Comment: For the last one, you can also add `.try_into().unwrap()` to get a `Box<[i32; 1000]>`. The result is identical to the unsafe one! I didn't expect that. https://godbolt.org/z/aqzqK8jo1

Comment: `quux()` could make use of `vec!` and just return `vec![v; 1000].into_boxed_slice()`.

Comment: @user4815162342: You're absolutely right, but for *some* reason, the compiler decides to optimize [that one](https://godbolt.org/z/jTEsGf1oW) *slightly* differently (unroll by 8 instead of 10, fixup at the end),
which breaks my argument that the assembly is the same :D.

Comment: There's a nightly feature `new_uninit` which allows creating a `Box` containing an uninitialized `MaybeUninit<T>`, then call a _safe_ `write` function to overwrite the content of the `Box` _and_ make it a `Box<T>` at the same time, see https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021 . Still subject to optimizations, but _oh so much safer_ than `baz`.

Comment: You can skip the `into_boxed_slice` part. `Box::<[i32; 1000]>::try_from(vec![0; 1000]).unwrap()` works

Comment: @MatthieuM. Wouldn't the value passed to `write` be potentially allocated on the stack, thus having the same issue as `Box::new`? You didn't post the correct link to your code so I can't see what it does exactly.

Comment: `try_into::<T>()` does not work, because the generic parameter is on the trait, not on the method.

Comment: @interjay: Yes, as I noted "still subject to optimizations". The main difference, however, is that the memory allocation takes place _first_, so I'd expect that in practice it optimizes more often. Fixed link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2f5142756b7b3758ee437fd38bb91dd5

Comment: @MatthieuM. Unfortunately, if you show the assembly you'll see that your example initializes the array on the stack and calls `memcpy`, just like `Box::new`.

Comment: @interjay: Indeed. I was so happy to see the vectorized initialization that I missed the next block. Sigh :x In-place initialization is achievable (guaranteed), but I had to resort to one (wildly) unsafe method to achieve it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=d7c814396c1b72a87af44935d4ea92a9 :'(